# Google chrome extensions are corrupted constantly... It's really annoying

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Some of google chrome extensions have been corrupted constantly. In the period of 2 or 4 days, some extension's status are changed to "corrupted".

Then, I need to "Repair" every corrupted extensions. But, just a few days later, the situation repeats again and again and again..... During the period of time, nothing and no any single change makes for the google or computer at all. The extensions are just corrupted again and again... It is really annoying and wastes much time to repair.

What to do to prevent from it? Or, is there a way to "repair" all of corrupted extensions by clicking one single button?

Comment: Question: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a much more serious problem than re-repairing all your extensions at once:

***Why are they getting corrupted in the first place?***

Corruption means that something is *modifying your extensions*,
and this is entirely abnormal and even alarming.

The possibilities I can see are:

1. Your computer is infected (seems possible)
2. You have installed a rogue extension (less likely as extensions are sandboxed).
3. Legit extensions but corrupted profile
   (bad data that causes some legit extension to act strangely).

For the second case, you could remove all extensions and add them one by one
to check which one is doing it.

The first case is much more difficult. Read the following article for advice:
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

For the third and very rare case, start a new profile.

Comment: Don't you have a similar issue on your Chrome? It happens on mine always and it means there's extensions corruption nearly every day.

Comment: I never had extension corruption on Chrome or any other browser, which is why I'm worried about your problem.

Comment: Either of them are unlikely... I have multiple profiles and just on one exts get corrupted and mostly tampermonkey and uBO, but not others. These two are the most active ones. 3rd possibilities and most likely the profile is corrupted if it's old and due to constant altering of the way things get written with each new Chrome ver, some old exts use old methods, others newer, things will break at some point. Try to build a new profile, transfer ext and settings and try it out. I'll do that...

Comment: @JasonXA Thank you for the idea so much. I just reset my chrome profile yesterday and it seems to be ok now.

Comment: @JasonXA After resetting the profile, the kind of issues has not happened anymore. I hope you can post the answer again and I will give it to be the answer of the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: I see this rather as an extension of my answer, now in point 3 above.

Comment: Add one more culprit: recent use of LevelDB is unstable, since the issue was not present when Chrome used SQLite... if the db gets too large, they might be faster than SQLite but they will get corrupted. These db's are used to store mainly extension settings in the AppData ... Default (or Profile name) \ Local Extension Settings folder, each in a subfolder named per extension id. I was backing those up and restoring from the most recent backups, i.e. largest, but got corrupted again and again.

Comment: I proceed to export the settings where option was available, closed browser, removed the affected db, restarted browser and imported the settings again. So far no more corruption. uBO and TamperMonkey were among the affected with very large db files, 20MB+, for some reason. Right now uBO went under 12MB and TM is at 1.25MB. That's in case it's a localized issue and the user doesn't want to redo the whole profile.

Comment: @RayKao, it's OK, this answer can be updated, while the 1st two have a low likelihood because they seem plausible only on a targeted hacking attack scenario, normal viruses don't discriminate, they infect all programs and you'd feel it and rogue extensions won't live past a few days and be updated or removed from WebStore, thus invalidated, they + what I've posted add up to a complete answer.

Comment: Just an update. After 9 days since resetting the profile, the same issues have not happened again.

Answer (score 1):

#### It could be Tampermonkey.

Encountered a similar issue when we made a TamperMonkey script that used persistent storage.

JasonXA’s [comments above](https://superuser.com/questions/1349444/google-chrome-extensions-are-corrupted-constantly-its-really-annoying#comment2237889_1412354) seem like a plausible explanation—the database is getting too big, and Chrome’s implementation is not stable.

> Add one more culprit: recent use of LevelDB is unstable, since the issue was not present when Chrome used SQLite... if the db gets too large, they might be faster than SQLite but they will get corrupted. These db's are used to store mainly extension settings in the AppData ... Default (or Profile name) \ Local Extension Settings folder, each in a subfolder named per extension id. I was backing those up and restoring from the most recent backups, i.e. largest, but got corrupted again and again.

> I proceed to export the settings where option was available, closed browser, removed the affected db, restarted browser and imported the settings again. So far no more corruption. uBO and TamperMonkey were among the affected with very large db files, 20MB+, for some reason. Right now uBO went under 12MB and TM is at 1.25MB. That's in case it's a localized issue and the user doesn't want to redo the whole profile.